# Using Selenium ChromeDriver how to load saved extension settings?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `Selenium.WebDriver.ChomeDriver` v2.38.0 with `Chrome` v66.0.3359.117 (official build).

To continue discussion I will provide example extension. For this post I will use `Ghostery - Privacy Ad Blocker` v8.1.2.

Using C# I load the extension crx file, like this: (skipping the step of how I create the crx)

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExtension(workFolder + @"\Chrome32\extensions\8.1.2_0.crx");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Which works great: Ghostery loads to it's default settings. Which unfortunately are with all blockers disabled.

Switching back to my desktop and opening Chrome manually - I see that it did load my saved settings (everything blocked with Ghostery). Which tells me that somehow I need to load the saved settings programmatically. I'm fairly certain that during my manual browsing Chrome was able to do this because it loaded my Chrome user profile from `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

I already know that I can directly load this user profile using

```
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=" + @"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default");
```

But I do not want to use that profile. It is 70MB large, and has lots of other goodies associated with it that I don't want to use.

Instead, I want to programmatically load the saved extension settings, or, somehow save them in a place that will get loaded for me. Snooping around, I see that there is a `Extension State` folder in the user profile:

[image]

My hunch is that there must be a way to load these extensions settings in the Selenium way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the current state of a extension is stored, but you could try editing the extension-file.

For that, you need to extract your `.crx` file to a folder and then edit. If you're lucky, there already is some `.config`or other settings file.

You can also directly load extensions from a folder using the argument `--load-extension=path/to/extension_directory`